# Can I use two controllers in two different machine

Tags: corda

In my scenario, Transaction is between two nodes in two  different Machines. Currently am using a controller in Machine A which acts as a notary as well. Can i use two  controllers one in each machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed here: [Corda Controller Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48740538/corda-controller-node), Corda has no concept of a "controller" node.

Up until Corda 2, each network had a single network map node, no matter how many machines were involved. Each node's configuration file would point to this network map node, using its IP address and port number.

In Corda 3, the network map node was replaced with a server distributing network map files. Details about how to deploy a network across machines in Corda 3 can be found here: https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-cordapp.html#running-nodes-across-machines.

Comment: ok joel. i have three nodes as A,B,C. is that possible to do transaction between A and B where C is notary and transaction between B and C where A is notary?

Comment: Technically, a node can be both a notary and a regular node. However, production deployments would most likely separate these roles for reasons of conflict of interest.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can setup your case. NotaryChangeFlow (initiating), which should be used to change a state’s notary.

Comment: my question is can i define two networkMap for one cordapp?