# Corda Controller Node

Tags: blockchain, corda

With respect to Corda Nodes, Controller node serves as network map and offers
validating notary service. What if the controller node is shut down?
Will the other nodes function independently ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no concept of a "Controller" node in Corda. We simply gace the node that played the role of both the network map and notary the name "Controller" in our example application. In real deployments, these roles would be separate.

Regarding the shutdown of the network map/notary:

- If the network map goes offline, nodes can continue to communicate (as they each cache the network map), but no new nodes can join the network until the network map comes back online
- There can be many notaries on a network. Additionally, notaries can be clusters of nodes instead of single nodes, for either availability or Byzantine fault tolerance reasons. So if a single notary goes offline but is part of a cluster, there is no effect. If a notary goes offline and it is not part of a cluster, states assigned to that notary cannot be spent until that notary comes back online

Please also note that the design of the network map is changing. In the future, for availability reasons, the network map will no longer be a node. Instead, it will be a set of node info files distributed by a highly available service.

Answer (score 1):

network map node and Notary node can be separated from control node.  if network node shut down. transaction still can be made. but Notary is broken down that can't be made transaction.

Comment: So It means I can use any of my nodes to act as a notary. So even if one node fails the others nodes can function. Is my understanding correct ?